# jqueryui dialog relative to other dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to position two dialogs next to each other. I do the following:

```
$("#deck").dialog({
  width: 'auto',
  height: 'auto',
  position: {
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left bottom',
    of: '#title',
  }
});

$("#seats").dialog({
  width: 'auto',
  height: 'auto',
  position: {
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'right top',
    of: '#deck',
  },
});
```

However, this positions `#seats` to the right top of the `#deck` div, not the `#deck` dialog, so the two dialogs are not aligned because of the title bar difference. How would I position `#seats` relative to the `#deck`'s actual dialog? I've tried using an `of` of `#deck :parent`, `#deck :parent :parent`, and passing in the return value of `$("#deck").dialog(...)` but neither gave the desired result. I'd rather not hard-code the height of the title bar.

Answer (score 2):

The following works perfectly:

```
$("#seats").dialog({
  width: 'auto',
  height: 'auto',
  position: {
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'right top',
    of: $('#deck').parent(),
  },
});
```